# Sencha Touch 2 adding buttons to toolbar/titlebars

Tags: button, sencha-touch-2, toolbar, titlebar

Can anyone tell me how I might add buttons, or other components, to a title/tool bar without using the items array? For months I've been struggling to find a way to make the bar on all my views contain the same user buttons and icons.

It's a struggle mostly on List item detail views where only a back button shows. I want the back button but also own buttons on the same bar.  This is so my app has a uniform look and accessible functionality across the entire build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar and TitleBar extend Ext.Container. 
In Sencha Touch containers always store their components inside the items array.

If you want to have a toolbar that always look the same just create your own by extending Ext.Toolbar. Use the initialize method of such extended Toolbar to add the buttons/icons.

To use it with a list you can create a wrapping container, which contains the extended toolbar and the list.